# "Error dimention must agree" on Channel noise addition

Tags: matlab

I want to simulate the effect of CRC in Rayleigh Fading and AWGN. My code is as follows:

```
clear
NoBits =4; % number of bits
noPacket=4;

%-------------------------At the transmitter-------------------------------

DataIn =randi([0,1],noPacket,NoBits); % generating 0,1 with equal probability

%~~~~~~~~~~Cyclic Redundancy Check (CRC)~~~~~~~~~~
            div=[1 0 0 1];        % predetermined divisor
            for i=1:noPacket
                [q,r]=deconv(DataIn(i,:),div); 
               y(i,:)=[DataIn(i,:),zeros(1,3)];
               for k=1:NoBits
                       r(k)=mod(r(k),2);
               end
               fcs=[zeros(1,3),r];        % frame check sequence  
               DataOut(i,:)=bitxor(y(i,:),fcs);
            end

%~~~~~~~~~~BPSK Modulation~~~~~~~~~~   

BPSK1 = 2*DataOut-1; % BPSK modulation 0 -> -1; 1 -> 0 

Eb_N0_dB = [-3:35]; % multiple Eb/N0 values
%-------------------------Channel Modelling-------------------------------

for ii = 1:length(Eb_N0_dB)

   awgn = 1/sqrt(2)*[randn(1,NoBits) + j*randn(1,NoBits)]; % white gaussian noise, 0dB variance 
   Ray = 1/sqrt(2)*[randn(1,NoBits) + j*randn(1,NoBits)]; % Rayleigh channel

 % Channel and noise Noise addition
 y = Ray.*BPSK1 + 10^(-Eb_N0_dB(ii)/20)*awgn; 

%----------------------------At the Receiver-------------------------------
      % equalization
       yHat = y./Ray;
    % receiver - hard decision decoding
   recDat = real(yHat)>0;

   % counting the errors
   nErr(ii) = size(find([DataIn-recDat]),2);

end

simBer = nErr/NoBits; % simulated ber
theoryBerAWGN = 0.5*erfc(sqrt(10.^(Eb_N0_dB/10))); % theoretical ber
EbN0Lin = 10.^(Eb_N0_dB/10);
theoryBer = 0.5.*(1-sqrt(EbN0Lin./(EbN0Lin+1)));

% plot
close all
figure
semilogy(Eb_N0_dB,theoryBerAWGN,'cd-','LineWidth',2);
hold on
semilogy(Eb_N0_dB,theoryBer,'bp-','LineWidth',2);
semilogy(Eb_N0_dB,simBer,'mx-','LineWidth',2);
axis([-3 35 10^-5 0.5])
grid on
legend('AWGN-Theory','Rayleigh-Theory', 'Rayleigh-Simulation');
xlabel('Eb/No, dB');
ylabel('Bit Error Rate');
title('BER for BPSK modulation in Rayleigh channel');
```

I've gotten the error "Error using  .* .Matrix dimensions must agree" on line :

```
y = Ray.*BPSK1 + 10^(-Eb_N0_dB(ii)/20)*awgn;
```

Hope anyone can help me solving this.

Comment: You're trying to perform element wise multiplication between a 1x4 vector and a 4x7 matrix.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you fully understand [element-wise](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/times.html) vs [matrix operations](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mtimes.html) in MATLAB.

The first one, where each of the operations are preceded by a dot, for instance `.*`, `./`, `.^` etc. means that you are doing an operation element-by-element. Thus, the matrices on each side of the operator must have the exact same size:

```
A = [1 2; 3 4]; B = [4 5; 6 7];
A .* B = [1*4  2*5; 3*6  4*7] = [4 10; 18 28]
```

The other type, the matrix operation operates on matrices:

```
A * B = [1*4+2*6  1*5+2*7; 3*4+4*6  3*6+4*7] = [16  19; 36  46]
```

Matrix operations can be performed on matrices of different sizes, as long as the dimensions match:

```
A = [1 2; 3 4]; B = [4; 6]; 
A * B = [1*4 + 2*6; 3*4+4*6] = [16; 36]
```

When you do `Ray.*BPSK1` then you're doing element-wise multiplication, thus the matrices must be of the same size. It's hard to know exactly what you want to achieve here, but there are a few alternatives that avoids dimension mismatches:

---

```
Ray*BPSK1
```

This will work, but will give you a dimension mismatch when you try to add the next term, since the result of the above expression will have dimensions `[1x7]`, and `awgn` has dimensions `[1x4]`.

---

```
BPSK1.'*Ray.'
```

This will work, but will give a result with dimensions `[7x1]`. You'll therefore have the same problem as above.

---

```
bsxfun(@times, BPSK1, Ray.')
```

This works, but will give you a `[7x4]` array, thus give you a new mismatch problem.